# How to remove multiple network manager applets?

Tags: network-manager

When I typed `nm-applet` in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, I got multiple network menu and I want to remove it.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If a reboot does not clear that up for you you can look inside the folder `~/.config/autostart` for the file `nm-applet.desktop` and move it somewhere else to test.

You can move the file by opening a terminal and typing `mv ~/.config/autostart/nm-applet.desktop ~/Desktop`, it will move the file to your desktop.

As an option you can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> in Nautilus to be able to see hidden files/folders, navigate to the `~/.config/autostart/` and move the file from there.

Don't forget to logout and back in after moving the file.

If this fails you can also check your startup applications list to see if you can disable it there. To have a look at your applications list open the user menu (cogwheel right next to the clock on the upper right corner) and click on *Startup Applications*.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. I found out that i had two files in my `/etc/xdg/autostart`, `nm-applet.desktop` and `nm-applet-mate.desktop` (which remained after MATE-desktop removing). So I've just removed the second one.

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu mate 18.04, on one box I had no nm-applet icon and two icons on another Ubuntu-mate box.

Both were resolved by inserting "dbus-launch" into the exec line in file:

`/etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop`

set:

```
Exec=dbus-launch nm-applet
```